# How can Paint.NET fix an image's colors just by opening and saving it?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, colors, png

[See this post on csssprites forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/smartsprites-css-sprite-generator/HDpWfyMUapw) and [this example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/464119/Programming/web/csssprites/bad-sprite-color.html).

I have an image (created using SmartSprites), that has incorrect colors caused by SmartSprites. The difference in colors is only observed when viewing this image in IE8.

When I open this image in Paint.NET and simply save it again (in 32bits color), it is "fixed".

I notice that my original image is 373 bytes, and after SmartSprites it's 339 bytes - so some bytes were lost ... but then opening and saving via Paint.NET enlarges it to 391 bytes, and "restores the missing information" somehow.

- What is going on here?
- Was information really lost when running SmartSprites?
- (Obviously not, because Paint.NET was able to restore it).
- What did Paint.NET do to restore it?

Comment: Kinda sounds like a classic case of a color profile being embedded in the PNG and IE freaking out... but I thought they fixed that in IE7.